# validating a django formset via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

All,

I have a Django View with an inline formset. When I access the view normally and submit it, everything works fine. When I access it via AJAX, though, I get a Validation Error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def edit_model(request):
    model_id = request.GET.get('i', None)
    if model_id:
        model = ModelClass.objects.get(pk=model_id)
    else:
        model = ModelClass()

    related_model_formset_class = inlineformset_factory(ModelClass, RelatedModelClass, form=RelatedModelForm,
                                                        prefix="my_related_models")

    if request.method == "GET":
        model_form = ModelFormClass(request.POST, instance=model)
        related_model_formset = related_model_formset_class(request.POST, instance=model)

        if model_form.is_valid() and related_model_formset.is_valid():
            model_form.save()
            related_model_formset.save()

            return HttpResponse("success")
    else:

        model_form = ModelFormClass(instance=model)
        related_model_initial_values = [{"default_value1": 1, "default_value2": 2},
                                        {"default_value1": 1, "default_value2": 2}]
        related_model_formset = related_model_formset_class(instance=model, initial=related_model_intial_values,
                                                            extra=len(related_model_initial_values))

    rendered_form = django.template.loader.render_to_string("my_form.html",
                                                            {"form": model_form, "formset": related_model_formset},
                                                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponse(rendered_form, mimetype='text/html')
```

This gets accessed from a JQuery call within another page (which has a similar structure as "my_form.html", with inline_formsets):

```
function edit_model(model_id) {

  var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/edit_model/?i=" + model_id

  var edit_model_dialog = $("<div></div>");
  $.ajax({
       url        : url,
       type       : "GET",
       cache      : false,
       success    : function(data) {
          var title = "here is a form to edit the model"
          edit_model_dialog(data);
          edit_model_dialog.dialog({
              title : title,
              modal : true,
              dialogClass: "no-close",
              close   : function() {
                  $(this).dialog("destroy");
              }
          }).dialog('open');
       }
   })
```

**Update:**

I still haven't solved this, but I've narrowed down the problem a bit.  The button that triggers the "edit_model" function is on another page that has its own forms and formsets of the same types as those that are rendered in the dialog that the button creates.  When submit is pushed on the form in the dialog, it seems to be triggering a POST from this parent page along with the page in the dialog.  Obviously, the management data on those two pages won't match.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to prevent submit on the dialog from propagating to the parent page.

Comment: in the form have you included `{{ form.management_form }}` ?

Comment: @karthikr - Yes, I have.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up changing my javascript to explicitly send a POST with the appropriate values rather than rely on the default "submit" behavior of the form in the dialog.  The new code looks something like this:

```
function edit_model(model_id) {

  var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/edit_model/?i=" + model_id

  var edit_model_dialog = $("<div></div>");
  $.ajax({
     url        : url,
     type       : "GET",
     cache      : false,
     success    : function(data) {
       var title = "here is a form to edit the model"
       edit_model_dialog(data);
       edit_model_dialog.dialog({
         title : title,
         modal : true,
         dialogClass: "no-close",
         close   : function() {
           $(this).dialog("destroy");
         },
         // HERE IS THE NEW BIT...
         buttons : {
           ok : function() {
             // GET THE DATA FROM THE FORM IN THE DIALOG...
             var form_data = $(this).find("the_form").serialize();
             $.ajax({
               url   : url
               // EXPLICITLY SEND IT AS A POST...
               type  : "POST",
               data  : form_data,
               cache : false,
               success : function(data) {
                 if (data == "success") {
                   $(edit_model_dialog).dialog("close");
                 }
                 else {
                   $(edit_model_dialog).html(data);
                 }
               }
             });
           },
           cancel : function () {
             $(edit_model_dialog).dialog("close");
           }
         }
       }).dialog('open');
     }
   })
```